# Nexus 5X records video rotated upside down using MediaRecorder and camera2

Tags: android, video-capture, android-mediarecorder, android-camera2

I'm facing the problem with recording video by new camera2 api. I'm playing with project from 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video
which demonstrates video recording using new camera2 api. Recording works well but rotation of recorded mp4 video is different because of different devices.

Nexus 9 result video is fine but Nexus 5X not.

**I've heard that Nexus 5X has camera rotated upside down**. In this case I would set MediaRecorder flags to record properly but...

**My question is, how to recognize programmatically whether device has or doesn't have camera rotated upside down?**

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution...

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
int sensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
```

`sensorOrientation` value: Default camera orientation used to be 90 degrees. For Nexus 5X it is 270 degrees.

Comment: Thanks, but then, how did you use sensorOrientation to fix the problem? You manually rotated the picture taken? Or did you found a way that the picture saved are directly in the right orientation?

Comment: Look at my pull request:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/pull/19
Line 591 (switch...) resolves orientation of recorded video

Comment: This shows you how to read sensor orientation, but does not show how or when you need to set the orientation so that your recorded video is properly displayed. I think it would be a more useful answer if you define what to do with your sensor orientation next. E.g. Do you rotate the bitmap in your ImageReader? Do you set a configuration on your CaptureRequest?

Comment: For video, you can set the orientation via MediaRecorder.setOrientationHint.

Answer (score 0):

After getting orienation from 
int sensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);

You can use
setOrientationHint(sensorOrientation) in MediarRecorder.